# How to use Jasper reports without templates

Tags: reporting, jasper-reports

I would like to use Jasper reports and build the report without templates. How can i get started? I have all the necessary libraries but I don't know how to start and I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Another Java frameworks for dynamic report's building are: [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/api-docs/) and [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try DynamicReports, an open source and based on JasperReports. Take a look at following [step by step](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html) tutorial.